# How to approach metrics and alerting of produced and consumed messages in grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, prometheus, grafana, metrics

I have problem with creating metrics and later trigger alerts base on that metric. I have two datasources, both are elasticsearch. One contains documents (logs from service) saying that message was produced to kafka, second contain documents (also logs from service) saying that message was consumed. What I want to achieve is to trigger alert if ratio of produced to consumed messages drop below 1.

Unfortunately it is impossible to use prometheus, for two reasons:
1) counter resets each time service is restarted.
2) second service doesn't have (and wont't have in reasonable time) prometheus integration.

Question is how to approach metrics and alerting based on that data sources? Is it possible? Maybe there is other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat generic (meaning no mapping or code, in general, is provided), so I'll provide an approach.

You can use a [watcher](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/how-watcher-works.html) upon an aggregation that you will create.
It's relatively straightforward to create a percentage of consume/produce, and based upon that percentage you can trigger an alert via the watcher.

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UVUzGMpyoo) (official elasticsearch channel) on how to do this. Moreover, check the tutorials for your specific version of elasticsearch. From 5.x to 7.x setting alerts has been significantly improved (this means that for 7.x you might be able to do this via the UI of kibana, but for 5.x you'll probably need to add the alert via indexing json in the appropriate indices `.watcher`)

I haven't used grafana, but I believe the same approach can be applied. You'll need an aggregation as mentioned before and then you add the alert https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/rules/